# Is texture filtering an anti-aliasing technique?

Tags: opengl, graphics, msaa

I know of anti-aliasing techniques with MSAA, but MSAA can only handle edges, but Shader sampling can handle internal pixels.

What's the difference between texture filtering and shader sampling, and is it also an anti-aliasing technique, such as Bilinear, Trilinear, which makes the image look smoother?

Comment: What does this have to do with C++ or programming?

Comment: It's a computer graphics question.

Comment: Your question reminded my on the paper [Avoiding Texture Seams by Discarding Filter Taps](http://jcgt.org/published/0002/02/07/paper.pdf) which argued about the similarity of texture filtering and multisampling in the spatial domain.

Answer (score 4):

**[Multisample Anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing)** (**MSAA**) is designed specifically for frame buffers and solve one problem - aliasing issues on geometry corners (pixelated / jagged triangle or line boundaries). MSAA texture cannot be used (in a straightforward way) for texturing 3D object.
[image: jagged sharp edges]

**[Texture filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering)** is a more general thing designed to solve aliasing and blurring issues while mapping 2D image onto 3D geometry. [Trilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_filtering) and [anisotropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_filtering) filters use mip-maps (cascade of downsampled images).

[image: Anisotropic texture filtering]

**Texture filtering** normally produces anti-aliased results within the textured geometry, but aliasing on geometry corners has different origin and cannot be eliminated by using some better texture filtering algorithm - that's why MSAA and texture filtering are applied independently in 3D engines.

Apart from MSAA, frame buffer anti-alising can be done by **[Super-Sampling Anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling)** (**SSAA**) technique - which basically renders scene into offscreen frame buffer of larger resolution and then resized to screen resolution using Bilinear texture filter (apparently, Trilinear filtering is of no use for stretching 2D rectangle) or another downsampling filter. Offscreen buffer might be also of smaller resolution than screen resolution, in which case Bilinear texture filter can be applied for upscaling image (producing blurry result).

**MSAA outwins SSAA** in ***performance*** with a **nasty trick** - while SSAA truly computes several samples per fragment, MSAA evaluates the Fragment Shader stage only ***once per fragment***. So that each sample within the fragment has initially the same color (including the one, that was retrieved from texture in a Fragment Shader), but depth values will vary per sample and each sample will be tested/blended individually with corresponding samples in MSAA frame buffer. This is why MSAA helps with anti-aliasing of *polygon edges*, but has no effect on *polygon's interior*. Fragment Shader with `discard` keyword does not benefit from extra samples in MSAA buffer either, as all samples are discarded or not discarded at once (producing jagged edges).

Modern APIs have an option called **Sample Shading** ([sampleShadingEnable](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#primsrast-sampleshading) in Vulkan, [GL_SAMPLE_SHADING](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMinSampleShading.xhtml) in OpenGL 4.0+) when rendering *into MSAA* frame buffer. This option asks renderer to truly execute the Fragment Shader within MSAA samples, practically making SSAA from MSAA. `minSampleShadingFactor` option controls the ratio between truly computed and masked samples, so that 1.0 means all samples computed (like SSAA) and smaller ratio would mix SSAA and MSAA techniques - as a compromise in performance (e.g. 8 MSAA with 0.5 ratio = 4 truly computed samples making anti-aliasing of polygon interior and exterior and 4 more samples used only for anti-aliasing jagged edges).

Comment: I kind of understand, but what's the difference between Shader sampling and texture filtering, for example, Vulkan has a sampleShadingEnable

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about `sampleShadingEnable` in Vulkan. I have tried to share my understanding of this feature in updated answer.

Comment: GL also has per-sample shading,  and so does D3D. It's a standard feature for GPUs and APIs since a long time.

Comment: @derhass, it would be more helpful specifying exact name of this feature in OpenGL or links to documentation (if you are not referring to directly accessing samples in GLSL, which is completely different scenario).

Comment: I see, there is `glMinSampleShading()` since OpenGL 4.0.

Comment: @gkv311 so what's the difference between Shader sampling and texture filtering...

Comment: @AndLightLight, *Shader Sampling* is just an option for executing Fragment Shader on all MSAA samples while *rendering* into frame buffer (NOT while reading from a texture). *Texture Filtering* is a functionality for *fetching* an interpolated value from a texture. It is rather difficult to formulate the difference, because I barely see a common part of these two features...